# checkbox value changes only when clicked twice in IE7

Tags: jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-7

I have a checkbox that has to display a lightbox when set to true. If I click the checkbox again , when the value is set to true, it should change the value to false and display an alert box. This works fine in Firefox.

But in IE7, when I click the checkbox when its value is set to true,the value does not change to false. So the lightbox is displayed again. Only when I click the checkbox again, the value is changed to false and the alert box is displayed.

```
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox"/>
 <a href="lightbox.html?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&modal=true" class="thickbox" id="lightbox_link"></a>
```

I have used the change function to change the value of the checkbox and display correspondingly.

```
 $("#chkbox").change(function(){

     alert(this.checked); //returns true in IE when clicked for the second time
     if(this.checked)
            {
               $("a#lightbox_link").trigger("click"); //displays the lightbox

            }
            else
            {
                $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                        resizable: false,   
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {  
                                   "OK": function() {
                                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );   
                                    },          
                                    Cancel: function() {
                                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );   
                                         $("#chkbox").attr("checked", true);    
                                    }                   
                                }
               })
            }

});
```

Comment: Five bucks says that the `.change` function occurs before IE sets the value of `checked` to true

Answer (score 1):

Its better to handle `click` event on checkbox. Then inside function you may check `$( this ).attr( 'checked' )` and then handle this click by showing lightbox or hiding it.

**EDITED**

also use `$( this ).attr( 'checked' )` instead of this.checked.

Comment: Your suggestion works,thank you, but I have to reverse the if ,else conditions, because the event of displaying the lightbox or alertbox is triggered first. Hence I've changed `if(this.checked)` to `if(!this.checked)`. But not sure if this is a proper way of coding. Anyway, I've got the needed solution for now. Would like to know other suggestions also.  And regarding `$( this ).attr( 'checked' )`, it was written in many posts that `this.checked` is good for optimised performance, that is why I had used it.

Comment: this.checked is access to direct select property without jQuery wrapper. $( this ).attr( 'checked' ) reads this property throught jQuery. In your example there is highload, so I prefer to use the second way. But this is just my imho))

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the `change` event in IE, version 5.5, 6.0, 7.0 and 8.0 will not function properly when the `change` event is used.

[According to Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html),

> IE 5-8 fires the event when the checkbox or radio is blurred, and not when it is activated. This is a serious bug that requires the user to take another action and prevents a consistent cross-browser interface based on the change event on checkboxes and radios.